# Bootstrap 3 - Change dropdown background colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm quite new to Bootstrap, I've set up a dropdown pill and played around with the colours.

What I'd like to do is change the colour of the dropdown title pill after it has been selected.  It currently changes to a light grey:

[image: dropdown screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row hidden-xs">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified nav-filter">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Valentine's Day</a></li>

      <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
          Recipient <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Occasion</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Type</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">New</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">On Sale</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

What would the CSS be to overide this colour? - not the dropdown itself, just the title link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would override the hover, active and focus state of `.nav-pills` like this..

```
.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #FF6699;
}
.nav-pills .open>a, .nav-pills .open>a:active, .nav-pills .open>a:focus{
    background-color: #FF6699;
}
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/7knejiguxy)

Comment: This works really well! In your demo if you click "recipient" twice (and then mouseout) it turns grey.  Is there any CSS to overide this too? Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior. What browser are you using?

Comment: I've tried it in Firefox, Chrome and IE - I get that behaviour in all 3.  Hover - Pink, Click Once - Pink, Click again - Pink, Mouse Out - Grey.  If that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

This will change the background/text color of the active class (inc. focus):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following css:

```
.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:hover, .nav .open>a:focus{
background-color: red;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
background-color: red;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skL5H/66/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav>li>a:hover,.nav>li>a:visited {
     background-color: #222; /* add your desired color */
}
```

Comment: @AK_  a:hover stands for when the anchor tag gets hovered. a:visited stands for after the anchor tag gets visited !

Comment: Cool... Its not for me, its for the OP, and anyone who will google this in the future. You should always try to give a complete and well explained answer. Also you can edit your answers.